# CQL insert returns "CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [list<varchar> <-> java.util.HashMap]"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I think I'm missing something in my code and my query. The code below gives me the following error (under the code).

I think it's because my data and table does not match but everything looks fine.

Could somebody help me?

```
public void insertFarmers( \
  int id, String city, HashMap<String, String>the_farmers, List<String>foods, \
  List<String> delivery, int food_id, int cost, HashMap<String, String>food_item, \
  String unit) {
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
        .addContactPoints(serverIP)
        .build();
    try (Session session = cluster.connect("farm_db")) {
        String insert_query = "INSERT INTO farmers \
            (farmer_id, city, foods, delivery, the_farmers, \
            food_id, cost, food_item, unit) \
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pStatement = session.prepare(insert_query);
        BoundStatement bStatement = pStatement.bind(id, city, the_farmers, foods, \
            delivery, food_id, cost, food_item, unit);
        session.execute(bStatement);
    }
}
```

THE ERROR:

```
CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: \
    [list<varchar> <-> java.util.HashMap]
```

```
 farmer_id | city | cost | delivery | food_id | food_item | foods | the_farmers | unit
-----------+------+------+----------+---------+-----------+-------+-------------+------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema doesn't match your code. You have a column with type `list<text>`, but trying to insert `map<text, text>`

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that there is a mismatch between your schema and the code.

One of the columns in your table has a CQL type `list<varchar>` but you are inserting a `HashMap` data type which isn't compatible with CQL `list`.

Comment: Thank you @Erick and @Alex! Is their a special rule to go after how to know in which order the columns are going to end up in?

Comment: By "table schema", I meant the CQL `CREATE TABLE` schema which shows the columns, their corresponding data types and `PRIMARY KEY` definition. 